# Adjust line break when pressing ALT+Shift+F in VS-Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm actively using the keybinding ALT+Shift+F for auto formatting my code. I love it and it works well, despite that the line break is set too early.

For example:[image]
I want `MyThemes.light` to be in the same line, not in the next.
There's still plenty of room to the right, that's just not used. So is there a way to adjust the value at which point the auto format inserts a line break?

Would really love to fix this, as VS-Code is my all time favorite code editor.

Comment: Are you using a custom formatter or just VSCode's internal formatter?

Comment: Yes, I'm just using the VS-Code's internal formatter. All I've installed are VS-Code themes. Using it for Dart & Flutter, if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to adjust this was setting the `Dart: Line Length` paramter in the VS-Code Settings.
The auto-formatter uses this for making proper line breaks.

The default value `80` seems a bit low on 16:9 monitors and bigger displays. Maybe someone else will find this useful.